# C# accessing element of object from List<> using for loop instead of foreach

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, object, arraylist

trying to brush up my foundation on C#. How do I print the value of objects from a List? I have a List and wants to print out the Name and Age to console.

I can use foreach loop to print them out easily with whole name and age but I am just curious how to do it through a for loop here is my code which I fail of coz
Thank you for your opinion and help

```
namespace Rextester
{
    public class Person
    {
        
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public int Age {get; set;}

    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            
            var People = new List<Person>
            {
                new Person{Name ="mary", Age= 60},
                new Person{Name ="john", Age = 40},
                new Person{Name ="peter", Age= 50},
                new Person{Name ="jane", Age=30}
            };

            foreach(var obj in People)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(obj.Name + obj.Age);
            }
            
            for(int i=0; i<People.Count; i++)
            {
                var name = People[i].Name;
                var age = People[i].Age;
                Console.WriteLine(name[i]); // result is char in each index of string m, o ,t, e  instead of name - mary, john, peter, jane
                Console.WriteLine(age[i]);// error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `name` should be a string, so you can index each letter (char) - if that is what you want. Age is an int which cant be indexed because there are no meaningful component elements.

Comment: The error says it all. `var age= People[i].Age` sets `age`  to be an `int`. So if you want to print the `age` just use `Console.WriteLine(age)`. Same for name. This doesn't throw an immediate error for the first few items, because you can access individual chars of a string via index `[i]`. But once your `i` is greater than the length of the name, this will also throw an error

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp thank you! that make sense :)) now i got it

Comment: @derpirscher Thank you! so i was over thinking. It is that simple.... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost did everything by yourself:

```
Console.WriteLine(People[i].Name);
Console.WriteLine(People[i].Age);
```

Comment: Or simply `Console.WriteLine(name);` and `Console.WriteLine(age);`